# Can the M1 Macbook Air compile Android source code without problems?

Tags: macos, java, development, apple-silicon, android

Do I need a x86 system to build and compile Android source code? Will it work on M1 Macbook Air to build a Android rom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sure can use the M1 Air.

- https://medium.com/@ishanknijhawan/android-development-on-m1-mac-this-is-how-it-should-be-done-3e7d2f0492cf
- https://developer.android.com/studio

There is an arm build so I would start with that and only worry about IntelliJ if you run out of memory or don’t like the standard install.

Answer (score 3):

I am developing mobile apps and some of them are developed with Flutter, also, friend of mine is an android developer we both are using M1 Macs and not facing any issue.

If you have a Macbook Air with 8GB RAM, it won't be a big problem but it might slow you down when you need to run another software like photoshop, second IDE etc. beside Android Studio but 8GB is just enough for Android Studio and one emulator.